# Keyboard handler to move a shape in response to arrow keys

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom

I finished Codeacademy and I'm looking to practice and get better at JavaScript. Is this coded correctly or should I have made a function for it somehow?  The purpose of this code is to move a square around the page with arrow keys or buttons.

I have the entire script hosted [here](http://guyu.5gbfree.com/test.html).

I mostly want to "Simplify this chain of if statements"  but also the post  about using a map instead of the if statements is something I needed to know.

```
function anim(e){
    if((e.keyCode === 37)||(e === 37)){
      y = shipLeft;
      shipLeft -= 11;
      y -= 11;
      y.toString();
      y = y + 'px';
      ship.style.left = y;
      changeColor();
    return shipLeft
}
    else if ((e.keyCode === 39) || (e === 39)){
      y = shipLeft;
      shipLeft += 11;
      y += 11;
      y.toString();
      y = y + 'px';
      ship.style.left = y;
      changeColor();
    return shipLeft
    }
    else if ((e.keyCode === 40) || (e === 40)){
      y = shipTop;
      y += 11;
      shipTop += 11;
      y.toString();
      y = y + 'px';
      ship.style.top = y;
      changeColor();
    return shipTop;
    }
    else if ((e.keyCode === 38) || ( e === 38)){
      y = shipTop;
      y -= 11;
      shipTop -= 11;
      y.toString();
      y = y + 'px';
      ship.style.top = y;
      changeColor();
    return shipTop;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Proper code indentation would really help a lot.  I can't even really attempt to read it without first fixing the formatting.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please take a moment to edit your title and question to explain what the code is doing. See [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/42632)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please fix up your post. No where do you say what your code is doing (a title would be a good place). I also recommend [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/checklist-for-how-to-write-a-good-code-review-question/6429#6429) to improve your question.

Comment: i think i have seen these same comments on every post...

Comment: The problem with the if statements is obvious enough. The objection that some users have is likely that your question didn't write a description of the _purpose_ of the code (which is only apparent after seeing the off-site demo).

Comment: oh, that does make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move `shipLeft` and `shipTop` into an object called `shipPositions` rather than just top level variables, you could also use a map-driven approach like this:

```
function anim(e) {
    var key = e.KeyCode || e, val, info;
    var keyMap = {
        "37": {direction: "left", ship: "shipLeft", delta: -11},
        "39": {direction: "left", ship: "shipLeft", delta: 11},
        "40": {direction: "top", ship: "shipTop", delta: 11},
        "38": {direction: "top", ship: "shipTop", delta: -11},

    };
    info = keyMap[key];
    if (!info) {
        return;
    }
    shipPositions[info.ship] += info.delta;
    val = shipPositions[info.ship];
    ship.style[info.direction] = val + 'px';
    changeColor();
    return val;
}
```

Comment: thanks!  I was also stuck on this.  I was thinking I should use a 2d array... but that didn't work out (for me atleast).  I will try this out!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, each branch of your if/else does the following:

1. Update the appropriate `shipXXX` variable with an appropriate increment.
2. Set the appropriate `ship.style.xxx` value.
3. Call `changeColor()`.
4. return the newly modified value.

The last three steps are pretty much the same for all branches once you have the value and know the style name.  So, you can move those three steps to a common place and do them once and just set up the appropriate state in the if/else.

Also, this structure:

```
(e.keyCode === 37)||(e === 37)
```

Is repeated each time.  Since there can't be a case where `e` is an object that has a `.KeyCode` property and where `e ==== 37`, then you can figure out once before all the comparisons whether there is a `.KeyCode` property or not and just use that knowledge.  This also simplifies the comparisons.

I'm also assuming that the variable `y` in your code is just something you are temporarily using and not something you're really trying to set (it appears to be an accidental global and is not being used elsewhere so I've removed it).

You can extract out some of the repeated code like this:

```
function anim(e) {
    var direction, val, key = e.KeyCode || e;
    if (key === 37) {
        direction = "left";
        shipLeft -= 11;
        val = shipLeft;
    } else if (key === 39) {
        direction = "left";
        shipLeft += 11;
        val = shipLeft;
    } else if (key === 40) {
        direction = "top";
        shipTop += 11;
        val = shipTop;
    } else if (key === 38) {
        direction = "top";
        shipTop -= 11;
        val = shipTop;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    ship.style[direction] = val + 'px';
    changeColor();
    return val;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I like the way you went through your thought process!  I'll definitely try that out and use it on my next project.  Both comments are incredibly useful for someone starting out!